# What is the definition of a non-linear estimator? I heard that ratio of estimators is non-linear

Tags: linear, estimators, definition, nonlinear, nonlinearity

> [Why don't we consider nonlinear estimators for the parameters of linear regression models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276661/why-dont-we-consider-nonlinear-estimators-for-the-parameters-of-linear-regressi)
> says that LASSO is a non-linear estimator.

I think LASSO has a solution via matrix multiplication. I don't even think that comment from quote is true.

What is definition of non-linear estimator?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-linear+estimator.  Ratios of estimators can be linear, btw.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps [this will help.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=linear+function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear estimators of the regression parameters are defined as linear functions of the outcome, typically denoted by $y$. Nonlinear estimators are estimators that cannot be written this way.

The OLS solution is a linear estimator because $\hat\beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, so a linear function of $y$ (some matrix times $y$).

For LASSO regression, there is no such closed-form solution where the parameters are written as a matrix times the $y$ vector.